# Whenever I add buttons to kivy, the background image disappears

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, button, kivy

So, as said above, I'm having problems with button overlay, when I add an image (background image) and a button over it, the button just gets opened in a new window, which i don't want.

I tried putting button over the image, but that just results in button being first to open. I want to place the button somewhere on the background, in the same window.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.